# Do I actually need to use React.js if I am not comfortable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have a project which should be submitted next week and wanted for my personal use to work with React.js . I spent almost 2 weeks working with React.js . So I can make more full mern Stack Application . I learned React from different Websites and references but Yet not Comfortable with working with React.js . I think It is more sophisticated than I thought . I am comfortable with Mongodb , express and Node but didn't got R (for React) on my resume . So tried to master it and apply with real life experience but got NoSense

It is necessary to use React to have the features like useState (or maybe localStorage will WorkOut ) . And what is the alternative of React.js that can be grasped fast as possible which is powerful like React.js (Please don't take the name of Angular.js or Vue.js or Vanilla JavaScript) and also had a great features Like React.js and what is the alternative of react-router-dom (Link Component) which loads the pages without Reloading the full page ?

Comment: Try https://svelte.dev/

Comment: Try vue.js https://vuejs.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the **SSR (Server side rendering)**. I can tell one of the examples for SSR is NextJS (https://nextjs.org).

This website builds on NextJS: [https://wantjson.com](https://wantjson.com/)

Check the code here: https://github.com/ZaHuPro/wantJSON